# Is there a way to tar multiple files in a directory (Linux/Unix)?

Tags: files, tar

Is there a fairly simple way to `tar` several (specific) files in a directory? For example let's say the following is a directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 allend bin     98 Jul 20 15:50 scriptlog.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 allend bin  19533 Jul 29 21:47 serveralert.log
-rwxr--r-- 1 allend bin   1625 Jul 29 21:47 orion
-rw-r--r-- 1 allend bin  24064 Jul 29 21:49 orion_files.tar
-rwxr--r-- 1 allend bin    156 Aug  4 21:22 htmltest
-rw-r--r-- 1 allend bin    131 Aug  4 21:23 page.html
```

What if I only want to `tar` the files `serveralert.log` and `page.html`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Is there something wrong with listing the files you'd like to add to the .tar file?

```
$ tar cvf some.tar file1 file2 file3
```

#### Example

```
$ tar cvf some.tar serveralert.log page.html
serveralert.log
page.html
```

Comment: I see. I found out what the problem was with your help. I had been adding an "-" to tar options. This was causing it not to work for me. I'm sorry it seemed that I had not done any research on this matter. Thank you very much for your help in this matter.

Comment: You could also compress all files using pattern matching. E.g. tar cvf *.csv

Comment: If you have too many files and you end up with a `Argument list too long` error then you can use `find` instead. See [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/642520/115443).